# OOP iterator and find method not working correctly

Tags: c++, oop, dictionary, find

```
Doctor Hospital::findDoctor(const Doctor &doctor) {
    map<int, Doctor>::iterator iter = find(hospitalInner->doctors.begin(), hospitalInner->doctors.end(), 5);
}
```

Hy, I'm having some problem with this exact method. Maybe someone know where is the problem? (I'm adding current error.)

error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::pair' (or there is no acceptable conversion) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xutility 3026    1   hospital5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find the element with a particular key, use the member [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) function (rather than the `std::find` algorithm):

```
map<int, Doctor>::iterator iter = hospitalInner->doctors.find(5);
```

You could achieve this with `std::find`, but you would have to write a custom comparator that checks the `first` member of each `std::pair` in the map (a `std::map` stores its keys and values as `std::pair`s).